# Will Log writing in text file affect performance of a website?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website. I am writing log files to get total time span for the page.Does writing log in txt files affect the performance of my program? I am logging this in events like `OnUnload`.

```
string logString = string.Format("The total time span for the '{0}' is {1}ms",
                                 _page, 
                                 span.TotalMilliseconds);
WriteLog(logString);
```

Log excerpt:

```
8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 3121.1785ms
[8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 5.0002ms
[8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 5.0003ms
[8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 4.0002ms
[8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 5.0003ms
[8/6/2013 05:38:27]:The total time span for the 'Assign' is 6.0004ms
```

Comment: How many concurrent users do you expect? Probably not an issue with a few users, but a few hundred thousand may negatively impact your app. Is this something you could get from IIS logging? (Why reinvent the wheel if you don't have to)

Comment: There are only some users but i have seen in the code that log is writing several times in an second

Comment: I have pasted the log in my question above

Comment: @anish : The frequency of logging can be reduced. For ex: if any issue or particular info occurs with in the event, that you might expect to log.

Comment: I am writing exception logs in another file.But i have seen in my project that a log file is writing several times in an second to get The total time span.I want to know whether this affect the performance.The log is writing if we are not performing any actions in page also

Comment: Yes. logging affects the performance because it is an additional step you perform. This is why you have different log levels and in production you select the log level such that logging is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing *something*, and *anything* will affect your performance. Writing to a file is relatively slow, so yes, it will do *something* to your performance. How much depends on your hardware configuration, and frankly, on your `WriteLog()` method which you didn't show.

Apart from this you'll have issues as soon as one process tries to write something to the log while another process is doing the same.

If you want to minimize performance impact, try to offload the logging as soon as possible, preferably to a different thread.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, the impact is most likely not going to be affected. At least not noticeable is long as your are not logging to much. You should look at a logging framework like [log4net](http://www.eyecatch.no/blog/2012/08/logging-with-log4net-in-c-sharp/). It will do alot of things for you, **like writing to the txt file after a given amount of logs**. This will reduce the amount writes to a file.

If you want to do it yourself I would recommend performing the log on another thread, like this:

```
var thread = new Thread(message =>
    {
        // write message to txt file.
    });

thread.Start("This is a log statement");
```

This way it won't occupy your main thread. However, writing to a file is quite dangerous using multiple threads. You'll need some locking:

```
private static readonly object _writeLock = new object();

var thread = new Thread(message =>
    {
        lock (_writeLock)
        {
            // write message to txt file.
        }
    });

thread.Start("This is a log statement");
```

Now you are sure that there is only one thread writing to the file. I would still recommend using log4net or any other framework that does this job for you.

Comment: OK thank you.But i have asked about the way i have already implemented.Will the logging in several times in an second affect the performance?

Comment: Implementation can be redone, I guess. And the answer to that question is dependent on your hardware. In your current situation: I think so. Just because you are writing to a file for every log statement. Multiple users could cause some performance issues.

Comment: Again, my advice: use an existing framework. People who made those frameworks most probably had performance in mind when developing it. Don't re-invent the wheel.

Comment: There is a problem here: if writing the log fails, the worker process crashes hard because of an unhandled exception.

Comment: This is example code. The usage of `using` and `try ... catch` is something the developer needs to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it effect the performance of the application, the effect is directly proportional to the number of users

Answer (score 0):

If you only need time take, IIS log has that by default.

[Default IIS log format](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/bea506fd-38bc-4850-a4fb-e3a0379d321f.mspx?mfr=true) (says IIS6 and win server 2003, but this is the default in newer versions as well.

```
time-taken: The length of time that the action took, in milliseconds.
```